# Accessing Windows Phone 7 database externally

Tags: database, sqlite, windows-phone-7

I've just started working on Windows Phone. Can anyone help me access my project database? 
I've tried with ISETool.exe 
I did this:

```
ISETool.exe ts xd 77a80316-355d-40dc-a8c3-c4054676e85c "C:\Users\user\Desktop\isostore"
```

but I'm getting an error in cmd:

> The application is not installed

I've also tried using WP7 Isolated Storage Explorer from:
http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/

But it doesnt see any devices or emulators.

It's Windows Phone 7 project. I've opened it in Visual Studio 2012 running on Windows 8.

It's frustrating loosing so much time on such a basic thing. Please help!

Comment: I've had success with Windows Phone Power Tools in the past: http://wptools.codeplex.com/

Comment: @MichaelItzoe This worked. Thank you! Can you please post an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had success with [Windows Phone Power](http://wptools.codeplex.com) Tools in the past. Even though the project is labeled "for WP8" it still works with 7.5 on Windows 8 with the WP8 SDK installed.

Comment: I just want to say that I've managed to view the exported data with SQL Query Data Analyzer.